# multidimensional array php to select2 data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I use codeigniter for a webapp, i can get the data from my db into a array

i have this multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Comerciales
            [1] => Array
                (
                [0] => Terreno
                [1] => Galera
                [2] => Oficinas
                [3] => Locales
                [4] => Playas e Islas
                [5] => Edificios
                [6] => Hoteles
                [7] => Propiedades de Inversión / Desarrollo
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Residenciales
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Ciudad
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Terreno
                                [1] => Casa
                                [2] => Apartamento
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Montaña
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Terreno
                                [1] => Casa
                                [2] => Apartamento
                            )

                    )



            )

    )

)
```

I need to pass to a select2 data but de data i need is sonething like thad, i prove sone loop in php but i cant make it work. Please sorry for my english.

```
var theData = [{
"id": "CEN",
"level": "C",
"dataid": "EN",
"text": "England",
"children": [{
    "id": "RDEF",
    "level": "R",
    "dataid": "DEF",
    "text": "Default Region",
    "children": [{
        "id": "D100",
        "level": "D",
        "dataid": "100",
        "text": "Depot 100"
    }, {
        "id": "D125",
        "level": "D",
        "dataid": "125",
        "text": "Depot 125"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "RNORTH",
    "level": "R",
    "dataid": "NORTH",
    "text": "North Region",
    "children": [{
        "id": "D999",
        "level": "D",
        "dataid": "999",
        "text": "Depot 999 - Head Office"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "RWEST",
    "level": "R",
    "dataid": "WEST",
    "text": "West Region",
    "children": [{
        "id": "D555",
        "level": "D",
        "dataid": "555",
        "text": "Depot 555"
        }]
    }]
}, {
"id": "CNL",
"level": "C",
"dataid": "NL",
"text": "Netherlands",
"children": [{
    "id": "RNORTH",
    "level": "R",
    "dataid": "NORTH",
    "text": "North Region",
    "children": [{
        "id": "DNL",
        "level": "D",
        "dataid": "NL",
        "text": "Dutch Depot"
    }
                    ]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($categorias); ?>;
alert(tempArray[0].Key);

Comment: are you getting any error when you run this? if so , what is the yo  error you are getting? it would be mighty helpful if you could paste it here?

Comment: is not just the error, is not what i need, i need to transform the first array into the second or something close

Comment: if you want to do that there should be some relation between the two arrays, which i'm not able to see. so if you can explain that , we can get somewhere

Comment: in the first array are father and sons just like the second.

Comment: that doesnt make much sense. you need to be more clear . sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what y do, i hope this help, if sone one can doit better please doit

```
 [<?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria){

foreach ($categoria as $key=>$parent) {
    if ($key==0) {  

    ?>{
"id": "<?php echo $parent['categoriaid']; ?>",
"level": "<?php echo $parent['parentid']; ?>",
"dataid": "<?php echo $key; ?>",
"text": "<?php echo $parent['nombre']; ?>"
        <?php }else {?>
,"children": [<?php 
 //necesario para colocar algo al final de cada registro y algo diferente en el ultimo
 $gdjci = array_keys($parent);
 $last_row = end($gdjci);
foreach ($parent as $key=>$children) {              
                  if (array_key_exists('nombre', $children)) {?>
    {    
    "id": "<?php echo $children['categoriaid']; ?>",
    "level": "<?php echo $children['parentid']; ?>",
    "dataid": "<?php echo $key; ?>",
    "text": "<?php echo $children['nombre']; ?>"}
                            <?php
                             if ($key == $last_row) {
        // last element
    echo "]},";
    } else {
        // not last element
    echo ",";
    }

    } else {

    //necesario para colocar algo al final de cada registro y algo diferente en el ultimo
                                $gdjci = array_keys($children);
                            $last_row = end($gdjci);
         foreach ($children as $key=>$parent) {
                    if ($key==0) {
                        ?>{ 
                    "id": "<?php echo $parent['categoriaid']; ?>",
                    "level": "<?php echo $parent['parentid']; ?>",
                    "dataid": "<?php echo $key; ?>",
                    "text": "<?php echo $parent['nombre']; ?>"
                            <?php
                                 if ($key == $last_row) {
                                            // last element
                                                echo "]";
                                        } else {
                                            // not last element
                                                echo ",";
                                        }

                    }else {
                            ?>
        "children": [
                                <?php
                            //necesario para colocar algo al final de cada registro y algo diferente en el ultimo
                            $gdjci = array_keys($parent);
                            $last_row = end($gdjci);

                            foreach ($parent as $key=>$children) {

                                  if (array_key_exists('nombre', $children)) {

                                    ?>{     
                                    "id": "<?php echo $children['categoriaid']; ?>",
                                    "level": "<?php echo $children['parentid']; ?>",
                                    "dataid": "<?php echo $key; ?>",
                                    "text": "<?php echo $children['nombre']; ?>"}
                                    <?php
                                     if ($key == $last_row) {
                                            // last element
                                                echo "]},";
                                        } else {
                                            // not last element
                                                echo ",";
                                        }
                                    } else {

                                            }


                                    }



                            }

                        }




                    }



            }



    }

}

}
echo ']'; 
echo '}]';
```